# Sort Based on Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

I am creating a `NSFetchedresultController` and I would like to sort the result based on class.

Say I have a parent class, `Car` with subclasses `Sedan` and `Coup`.

Can I sort them based on the subclass?

Comment: You can only sort on persistent entity properties.  If there's some kind of type field that differentiates the two, use that.

Comment: I don't have one, I was hoping I wouldn't need to. I can add it if needed.

Comment: you should not use sub-entities in your example case, you should use a ttpe identifier

Comment: @Wain Even if Coup and Sedan some different properties?  Car contains common properties, and Sedan has properties unique to itself and same for Coup.  Should all properties be lumped into Car and unused ones just remain nil?

Comment: You could try sorting based on the `_ENT` property, but I'd be surprised if core data let you get away with that.

Comment: there is little reason to use sub-entities really, it isn't more efficient and using a type is more functional. in the SQL table the attributes from other sub-entities are actually all in the same table and simply set to NULL